# Use variable "string" in compile-time commands

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is that possible  like this in C# , to define a variable, and assign that in declarations, like:

```
#define myVariable  "MyFile.dll"
...
[DllImport(myVariable, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern string someFunction(string directory);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can declare a constant, and then use that in attribute specifications:

```
public const string LibraryDll = "MyFile.dll";

[DllImport(LibraryDll, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern string someFunction(string directory);
```

That allows you to change the filename in a single place, if that's what you're looking for. You can use it from other types, too, e.g.

```
public static class LibraryConstants
{
    public const string DllName = "MyFile.dll";
}

public class OtherClass
{
    [DllImport(LibraryConstants.DllName, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern string someFunction(string directory);
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage to using this method over a config file? If the file being imported was going to need to be changed anyway, wouldn't a `.config` allow for more flexibility?

Comment: strange, I have change some code, including your suggestiong.. now,  I am getting "lock error.." now - https://i.imgur.com/LEGMVau.png , is that related to this?  or related to my other changes...

Comment: Ah, i've set that to "ignore" those message in VS, and now works.

Comment: @Symon: You can't use execution-time values in `DllImport` attributes. This approach would allow for different libraries to be used for different builds, for example.

Comment: @T.Todua; That would be nothing to do with this.